# Three Options - Enabling/Disabling based on input and record value

Tags: ms-access

I have a form where (among other things) there are three options which are intended to be exclusive.

- `optDealerPay`
- `optCustomerPay`
- `optNoTradeIn`

I want only one to be selected at a time, but when I originally designed this, I made these into three separate table columns instead of one and using an option group.  Mostly because of the output I'm wanting on a report I'm working on, too.  Anyway, when one is selected, the other two go `Enabled = False`.  The issue I'm having is when the form loads (actually using `Form_Current()` to ensure the record is loaded prior to "checking"), the form will disable one of the two options that are unselected, but not the other one.  Here is a picture:

[image: example1]

And here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    If Me.optDealerPay Then
        Me.optCustomerPay.Enabled = False
        Me.optNoTradeIn.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.optCustomerPay.Enabled = True
        Me.optNoTradeIn.Enabled = True
    End If
    If Me.optCustomerPay Then
        Me.optDealerPay.Enabled = False
        Me.optNoTradeIn.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.optDealerPay.Enabled = True
        Me.optNoTradeIn.Enabled = True
    End If

    If Me.optNoTradeIn Then
        Me.optDealerPay.Enabled = False
        Me.optCustomerPay.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.optDealerPay.Enabled = True
        Me.optCustomerPay.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

What's a better method to accomplish this outside of redesigning the table structure, which I'm really trying to avoid if possible.  Similar code is used with the `AfterUpdate()` procedure on each of the three options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code could essentially be reduced to:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
    optDealerPay.Enabled = Nz(optDealerPay, 0)
    optCustomerPay.Enabled = Nz(optCustomerPay, 0)
    optNoTradeIn.Enabled = Nz(optNoTradeIn, 0)
End Sub
```

That is, if a radio button is **null** or **unchecked**, then it is disabled; else it is enabled.

However, although this is the behaviour that you have requested, I'm not sure that this is desirable, as once the user has select an option they cannot change it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will execute every if statement one by one - that is some kind of mess. Make all radiobuttons enabled in design mode and try this code:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If Me.optDealerPay Then
        Me.optCustomerPay.Enabled = False
        Me.optNoTradeIn.Enabled = False
    ElseIf Me.optCustomerPay Then
        Me.optDealerPay.Enabled = False
        Me.optNoTradeIn.Enabled = False
    ElseIf Me.optNoTradeIn Then
        Me.optDealerPay.Enabled = False
        Me.optCustomerPay.Enabled = False
    Else
        ' Maybe you should do something if none of the options is true
    End If
End Sub
```